# AWS cognito: Store user auth token in backend server

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I am developing a react native mobile app and using server side API for managing user related data (backend). Currently I am using AWS cognito for supporting user signup/signin and all the user details are seems to be saved in AWS user pool.

I want to store auth token and user details on my server side, so that I can use this details to fetch user related data. So, I want the following approach to implement

Request:

```
Mobile App UI -> Server API (backend) -> AWS cognito
```

Response:

```
AWS cognito -> Server API (backend) -> Mobile App UI
```

Is this possible? If not what would be the best approach.

Comment: Are you using a SDK to interact with Cognito from your Server? If yes, which one?

Comment: I am using the Springboot server to interact with cognito-HakRo

Comment: If you store user details on a server is ok. but if you store how you're going to store token too and access user details ?
I would like to know this learn this.
What I used till now storing token at clientside and accessing user details by sending Token as auth credential.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Response**

If you are running Springboot in an EC2 instance you can asign a role to that EC2 instance with enought permissions and get data directly from your server app as an Administrator, i mean, using the SDK you can call AWS API requests just with that role, so you can retrieve the user data for all your users.

**Other options**

I think AWs has some services that make it easy to have this approach.

You can use Amazon Cognito Identity Provider to get credentials for an user and directly in the app you can call for example dynamoDB queries (etc) or you can do AWS API Gateway requests that are executed if the requests have valid credentials, this way you can call Lambdas and make some proccesing. If you need more details you should send more info to know the target of your app and make a better recommendation. Regards,